# ml.net Predict an outcome using historical data

Tags: ml.net

I am a complete to newbie to machine learning but I am trying to achieve following:

I have a series of data, let's say:

ie:
[ {'day1', 5}, {'day2', 3}, {'day3', 8} ... {'day100', 8}]

that at the end has a final result:

ie: pass/fail/other result

I would like to predict the most likely end result by using a partial set of data

ie: [{'day1', 3}, {'day2', 1}, {'day3', 6} ... {'day50', 8}]

What would be the best way to achieve this and if possible, do you have any examples or hint of where to look into that could help someone like me with no experience in machine learning

Comment: This is a really broad question. I would recommend linear regression to start. If you want to use ML.NET (as you tagged), I found this [Microsoft Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/predict-prices) very helpful when I was getting started.

Comment: when do you obtain the "final result" in the predict phase? Is it the result you face for **day51**?

Comment: So, this final result is obtained at the end of day 50.
What I am trying to achieve is based on past data (many other records that also go to day 50), see if the pattern, of day 1 to 25 for example, would give me a pass/fail/other. Effectively make a prediction by user previous results as an example

Answer (score 0):

It is a time series prediction.

I'd suggest you check if your time series contain trend or seasonality. Then try conventional methods of time-series prediction as [moving average](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411avg.htm) (or sliding window) when you, for example,  predict day 6 based on days 1-5, then day 7 based on days 2-6 etc. You may also try [Exponential Smoothing](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411avg.htm) and [ARIMA](https://otexts.com/fpp2/tspatterns.html).

Concerning **ml.net**, the following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/time-series-demand-forecasting) is the best solution for you
as it uses a **Singular Spectrum Analysis** and thus takes into consideration a trend and possible seasonality to forecast values. You can employ it by using
[ssaforecastingestimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.timeseries.ssaforecastingestimator?view=ml-dotnet): put window = 25 and horizon=1 if you want to use the first 25 days to predict the value for day 26 (prediction one step forward). I suggest you take a smaller window though (5-7 days).